# Database select all

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a database that contains some names and id of the name, and job,

and then created a page which shows you the name who works engineer.
but it shows me only the first one who work engineer.this is it's code

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('data');
$eng='engineer';
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `job` = '$eng'")or die(mysql_error());
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$name= $arr['name'];
$job= $arr['job'];
echo $name;
echo $job;
?>
```

Comment: PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

Comment: The sad thing is that the example #3 on the [mysql_fetch_array manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) - the **same page** that contains the **big red warning** @JoeFrambach is referring to shows you exactly what to do...

Comment: Regurgitating the manpages is what we're here for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have a look on how [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) works. It returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. They have [some good examples in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). You basically have to create a loop in order to archieve what you want.
2. The MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Try writing it like this:

```
...
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `job` = '$eng'")or die(mysql_error());

while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $name= $arr['name']; 
    $job= $arr['job'];
    echo $name;
    echo $job;
}
....
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_*()` only fetches a single row from the result set. You need to fetch in a loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $row['job'];
}
```

and also stop using the mysql_*() functions. They're obsolete and deprecated. I strongly urge you to switch to mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: mysql_fetch_* is a function, http://0-media-cdn.foolz.us/ffuuka/board/a/image/1357/96/1357963301931.jpg

Comment: grow up. there's four fetch functions, and I'm not going to write out all four of them when a single wildcard will suffice.

Comment: ohhh god there are more "four fetch functions" lol, i was just fun of php nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the resultset returned as a result of execution of mysql query.
Please try executing following code snippet

```
<?php
     mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('data');
     $eng='engineer';
     $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `job` = '$eng'")or  die(mysql_error());

     $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
    while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query))
     {
         $name= $arr['name'];
         $job= $arr['job'];
         echo $name;
         echo $job;
      }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modified version with some compression

```
..
$result= mysql_query("SELECT name, job FROM `data` WHERE `job` = '$eng'")or die(mysql_error());
if ($result)
{
  while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  {
    $name= $arr['name']; 
    $job= $arr['job'];
    echo $name.$job;

  }
}
..
```

// read prepare statement

Answer (score 0):

Check this one , I think this will help you

```
<?php
......
$result= mysql_query("SELECT name, job FROM `data` WHERE `job` = '$eng'")or     die(mysql_error());
if ($result)
{
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$name = $row['name']; 
$job= $row['job'];
echo "Name : " . $name ;
echo "Job : " . $job ; 

 }
 }

 .....

 ?>
```

?>